# generic return type for restemplate.exchange

Tags: spring-boot, resttemplate

I am using resttemplate.exchange to invoke a URL and get response. But the issue is the response type varies when I successfully receives the output and if I get some error.
eg.

```
ResponseEntity<XXX[]> response = restTemplate.exchange(endPoint,HttpMethod.GET,req,
            new ParameterizedTypeReference<XXX[]>() {},uriVariables);
```

If there is no issue with service and then output is in format of list. but if there is error like "NO DATA FOUND" then the response is in MAP. so whenever I have any issue with URL i get "404: null error" because my response type is unable to identify the error which is in MAP.

Could you please suggest what could be done as i can not change the response type of services.

Edit:: http://localhost:9090/data/getDetail?name=XXX
response [{"name":"XXX","Dept":"teaching","createdby":"YYY","createdDt":"06/09/2018"}]

when data not found case::http://localhost:9090/data/getDetail?name=YYY

response
{"response":"DATA NOT FOUND"}

Comment: I don't really get your question. What is the main problem? The parsing of the response body? Generally a HTTP status `404` is indicating a not mapped URL or no data found `REST` APIs

Comment: yes.. As the response of URL varies depending upon the situation if i successfully retrieve output I get response in LIST but if there is some error like "NO DATA FOUND" then the response is in MAP. and i can not change the response type because I wouldn't be knowing if I would be receiving any output or I am going to get error.

Comment: What do you want to extract from the response in case of "NO DATA FOUND"? For me this indicates that you don't get anything back. You could check the response status of the `ResponseEntity` in Spring and conditionally do something

Comment: Apparently the URL returns the response as below when there is "NO DATA FOUND"      {response: NO DATA FOUND} which is a Map type. SO i need to fetch this response

Comment: Could you please post the two possible results using something like `curl -i http://yourURL` and post both possible results in your question

Comment: I added the example..